# Modify value in array?

Tags: arrays, swift

So, I have a number of buttons that adds 1 to a counter. When a button is pressed the first time, it should add 1 to a array. When the button is pushed again, it should modify it to 2 and so on. Every button should modify its own number. Whats the best way to do this? I have tried to remove and insert with new value every time the button is pressed, but that don't seem like a good way to do it.

Comment: Please include relevant code (as text) in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First create Empty array

```
var arr = [Int](repeating:0,count:btnsCount)
```

then connect the buttons to same action

```
@IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender:UIButton) {
  arr[sender.tag] =  arr[sender.tag] + 1
}
```

Comment: Nice. Don't forget to set the tags for each of the buttons.